# react-jsonschema-form styling form elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-jsonschema-forms

As in the title can I style the inputs and labels directly in the schema via classNames props? If so than how? I have a following schema

```
  const uchema: JSONSchema7 = {
    type: "object",
    properties: {
      linkdata: {
        title: "Paste Link Here",
        type: "string",
      },
    },
    required: ["linkdata"],
  };

  const uiSchema: UiSchema = {
    linkdata: {
      "ui:autofocus": true,
      classNames: "flex flex-col my-4",
    },
    "ui:submitButtonOptions": {
      props: {
        disabled: true,
        className:
          "bg-white hover:bg-gray-100 text-gray-800 font-semibold py-2 px-4 border border-gray-400 rounded shadow",
      },
      norender: false,
      submitText: "Send",
    },
  };
```

the problem is that the submit button does not accept those tailwind classes, I still have

```
class="btn btn-info"
```

Do I need to make custom component for the field and for the label and for the button and every element I would like to use with it?

Thanks